# Are Task and Task<T> Interchangeable?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I ran across a typing situation while attempting to invoke a specific method overload, and now I'm curious: why does the following not induce a compilation error?

```
var a = (Task<Task>) (Task) null; // fine.
var b = (Func<Task<Task>>) (Func<Task>) null; // fine.
var c = (Task<Task<Task>>) (Task<Task>) null; // compilation error.
```

I would expect all of these examples to fail.

Error from the third line (`c`):
`Cannot cast expression of type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Threading.Tasks.Task>' to type 'Task<Task<Task>>'`

Comment: Perhaps you should include the compilation error in your question.

Comment: Well, `Task<T>` ***is*** `Task`...

Comment: @mason I'm not asking about the error. I'm asking about the lack of error.

Comment: @spender, yes, but a `Task` is not necessarily a `Task<T>`

Comment: If Task<T> is inherited from Task then it looks fine. It can result in runtime error thought

Comment: @cwharris The error is the most iteresting bit...

Comment: @spender fair enough, I'm now seeing that, based Michael's answer.

Comment: @DmitryPavliv Indeed. I wasn't looking at this from a hard casting perspective, so it wasn't making since from where I was standing. Looks fine now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Task<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321424(v=vs.110).aspx) derives from [`Task`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task(v=vs.110).aspx).

Your first line is sort of like doing `(int) (object) 1`, which is perfectly legal because everything (including `int`) derives from `Object`.

Your second line is the same thing with contravariance in action.

The third line fails because the `T` parameter of `Task<T>` is not set up for covariance (and indeed, it cannot be because `Task<T>` is a class, not an interface or delegate). It works for `Func<TResult>` because `Func<TResult>` *is* set up for covariance (i.e., it's declared as `Func<out TResult>`). Tasks may have been designed to disallow this on purposes, or they forgot to do it.

Comment: Because Task^3 is not inherited from Task^2

Comment: @Dmitry, no, it does not. I should have realized that. Both derive from Task, but Task^2 is nowhere in the hierarchy of Task^3.

Comment: Item 3 fails because `Task<T>` is not derived from a covariant interface/delegate. The `Func<out TResult>` is.

Comment: @spender Way ahead of you. :)

Comment: @spender `Task` is a class, and therefore cannot have co/contra-varience type arguments. This is a simple hard cast hierarchy issue.

Comment: @cwharris `GroupedEnumerable<T>` (for example) is a class, but derives from `IEnumerable<out T>` thereby allowing limited covariance. Why there's no `ITask`/`ITask<T>` interface is a question for the language designers.

Comment: @spender Eric Lipert doesn't seem to know, so I'm not going to pursue that. :)

Comment: @MichaelGunter Wait, so why doesn't `b` fail then. Neither `Task` nor `Func` have contra/co-varience, and therefore shouldn't both `b` and `c` fail?.

Comment: @cwharris `Func<out TResult>` does have contra/co-variance.

Comment: @MichaelGunter Derp. I was thinking `Func` was a class, not a `Delegate`, my bad.

Comment: @cwharris All good. I forgot generic classes don't support variance until you mentioned it.

Comment: @MichaelGunter I extrapolated on your answer as an extension of the question. Feel free to correct it if it's inaccurate.

Comment: @cwharris: What don't I seem to know?  (I'm not saying I know whatever it is, I'm saying I don't understand what you're referring to.)

Comment: On another question you posted a comment about how Task<T> was a good candidate to use a covariant interface instead of a class, but that whoever implemented it hadn’t based Tasks on an interface and therefore variance was out of the question. You hadn’t provided a reason why that was the case, though.

Comment: @cwharris I'll take your word for it; I don't recall. For that matter, `Task<T>` could have implemented `IObservable<T>` and yield exactly once; `IObservable<T>` is contravariant in T.

Comment: There’s technically nothing keeping anyone from using that approach, but it would introduce the ability for APIs to yield multiple values when they shouldn’t, and therefore bastardize the contract. Not a fan of that approach, but I can see it being used in a pinch.

Comment: @cwharris: Right, that would be weird. My point is simply that there is plainly no objection to making a covariant task, because an observable is a superset of the capabilities of a task.  The question of whether or not there should be an `ITask<T>` interface at all is a reasonable one; the push-back I would give if it were pitched to me would be "what three totally distinct types would implement this interface?" If I can't think of three implementations then it probably ought not to be an interface.

Answer (score 0):

This is an extrapolation of [Michael's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50707095/696056):

For `a`: `Task<T>` derives from `Task`, so this is OK.

For `b`: `Func` is a delegate with covariance, and therefore is implicitly converting `Task` to `Task<T>` on our behalf. `Func` is unaltered, and therefore this is OK.

For `c`: `Task` cannot use covariant type arguments since it is a class, and `Task<Task<T>>` does not derive from `Task<T>`, therefore this is NOT OK.